# RunningStatistics: Is there a way to track only a window of the last 5 samples?

Tags: math.net

`MathNet.Numerics.Statistics` has only `Push()` method, there is no `Pop()` method.

Let's say my window size is set to 5, and I've already sampled 5 values using `Push()`, I would want at that point that when I sample the next (sixth) value, it would remove the first value.

Because there is no method for removing a sample from the sampled values in a running/accumulating standard deviation, I am not able to track only the last window of the whole sampled values.

that way I could use my own logic for a fixed-sized queue and would be able to keep tracking the mean, variance and std. deviation without recalculating the whole last window of samples every time I sample a new value.

If there is no "Pop" method (to remove the first value), then is there already a feature like `WindowedStandardDeviation` when using `RunningStatistics` that I'm missing?

Comment: FYI: this is currently being worked on, see https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/264

Answer (score 1):

Since v3.7.0 there is a new class MovingStatistics that works like RunningStatistics but keeps track of the last N items only:

```
var s = new MovingStatistics(5);
s.Push(2.0);
// ....
var std = s.StandardDeviation;
```